# Progressively resizing a pane, by keeping an arrow button pressed

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, zsh, tmux

When pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>←</kbd> (or another arrow key) I am able to resize the current pane of one step only.

I was expecting to be able to resize the pane progressively by keeping the prefix and arrow keys pressed, however this is not the case because the key is then intercepted by the command line again.

How can I modify the `.tmux.conf` in order to behave correctly? I guess it has to do with something like changing the behavior of the prefix key, right?

**EDIT**

I am using zsh as my default shell. My `.tmux.conf` contains only the following (possibly unrelated) commands:

```
set -g mouse on        #For tmux version 2.1 and up
setw -g mode-keys vi
```

Answer (score 0):

The arrow keys to resize repeat by default (unless you've changed them), but you need to let go of the prefix key. So you need to press C-b Left then keep pressing Left.

If you hold down the arrow key rather than pressing it several times then it should work so long as `repeat-time` is longer than the system key repeat interval.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not my case. I am adding more info to the question.

Comment: Did you try increasing `repeat-time`? Try `tmux set -g repeat-time 10000` and see if it works, then reduce to find when it stops working. Make sure you are releasing the prefix though.

Comment: It works now, despite I have to press the combination C-b + arrow  twice, to activate the resize. The first time it's like the input is not captured.

Comment: Are you sure you are pressing C-b then Left, not C-b C-Left? Make sure you release ctrl and b before pressing Left.

Comment: If I do as you say, I just switch between panes. Am I missing something?